# Problem with C callback function in C# - how to pass value to a pointer?

Tags: c#, c, memory, callback, pointers

I've a C callback defined as follows:

```
Int16 (CALLBACK *ProcessMessage)(Uint16 ServerId,
   const char PTR *RequestMsg, Uint32 RequestSize,
   char PTR **ResponseMsg, Uint32 PTR *ResponseSize,
   Int16 PTR *AppErrCode);
```

An exemple of using this callback in C:

```
Int16 CALLBACK ProcessMessage(Uint16 ServerId, const char PTR *RequestMsg, Uint32 RequestSize, char PTR **ResponseMsg, Uint32 PTR *ResponseSize, Int16 PTR *AppErrCode)
{
    printf("ProcessMessage() -> ServerId=%u\n", ServerId);

    //**** SET THE VALUE FOR RESPONSEMSG (POINTER), THAT'S WHAT I NEED TO DO IN C# ****       
    sprintf(resp,"(%05lu) REPLY TEST", ServerId);
    *ResponseMsg = resp;

    printf("ProcessMessage() -> atribuido %p(p) a *ResponseMsg\n", *ResponseMsg);
    *ResponseSize = strlen(*ResponseMsg);
    *AppErrCode = -1; 
    return SS_OK;
}
```

Then I've this callback implemented in C#:

```
 [DllImport("Custom.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern Int16 SS_Initialize(
        UInt16[] ServerIds,
        UInt16 ServerQty,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string Binding,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string LogPath,
        UInt16 LogDays,
        Int16 LogLevel,
        UInt16 MaxThreads,
        UInt16 MaxConThread,
        ProcessMessageCallback callback);
```

Callback definition:

```
public delegate Int16 ProcessMessageCallback(
        UInt16 ServerId,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string RequestMsg,
        UInt32 RequestSize,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] ref string ResponseMsg,
        ref UInt32 ResponseSize,
        ref Int16 AppErrCode);
```

Method that sets the callback:

```
public void Call_SS_Initialize(
        UInt16[] serverIds,
        string binding,
        string logPath,
        UInt16 logDays,
        Int16 logLevel,
        UInt16 maxThreads,
        UInt16 maxConThread
        )
    {
        Int16 ret;
        try
        {
            pmc = new ProcessMessageCallback(ProcessMessage);

            ret = SS_Initialize(
                serverIds,
                Convert.ToUInt16(serverIds.ToList().Count),
                binding,
                logPath,
                logDays,
                logLevel,
                maxThreads,
                maxConThread,
                pmc);
        }
    }
```

And finally the Callback method, where THE PROBLEM IS:

```
public Int16 ProcessMessage(
      UInt16 ServerId,
      string RequestMsg,
      UInt32 RequestSize,
      ref string ResponseMsg,
      ref UInt32 ResponseSize,
      ref Int16 AppErrCode)
    {
       //Implement return to ResponseMsg POINTER
    }
```

The problem is, **ResponseMsg** is actually a **POINTER** in C. So in the C# method **ProcesMessage**, I've to set to ResponseMsg a space in memory (pointer) from where the DLL will get the string from.

I can't simply set ResponseMsg = "REPLY", because when the method finishes the memory where the string was is already destroyed.

How can I do that?? Please any advise is welcome!!

Thanks!

Comment: This looks OK to me at first glance. When you set ResponseMsg in your C# handler, what do you get back on the C end? A debug error? Garbage? Nothing?

Comment: I think that using `ref` there gives him double indirection - i.e. he doesn't actually pass a `char*` there, but rather `char**`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed the fact that it is indeed what is required!

Comment: Ben, it seems that the string is being gargabed, because the C program gets nothing on the ResponseMsg variable.

Pavel, I know almost nothing about C programming... can you explain better???

Comment: Looking more closely: what is the definition of PTR? ResponseMsg is defined as `char PTR **` .. is that `char ***`? Coz that won't work. :-)

Comment: @Rodrigo, in C code, what is the lifetime of `resp`?

Comment: Ben, it does'nt have any specific definition. As I can see it's like this: #define PTR.

Comment: Pavel, "resp" is a global field in the class...

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to recreate this. Maybe my experiment will help.

The C# code:

```
public delegate void ProcessMessageCallback(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] ref string ResponseMsg);

static class test
{
    [DllImport("test.dll")]
    static extern void TestCallback(ProcessMessageCallback callback);

    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestCallback(MyCallback);
    }

    static void MyCallback(ref string ResponseMsg)
    {
        ResponseMsg = "hi there";
    }
}
```

The C code (in a DLL):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "objbase.h"

__declspec(dllexport) void TestCallback(
    void (* CALLBACK managedCallback(char **)))
{
    char *test = NULL;
    managedCallback(&test);
    printf(test);
    CoTaskMemFree(test); // NB!
}
```

This successfully prints out "hi there".

Note: CoTaskMemFree should be used to free memory allocated by the P/Invoke layer. If you want to keep the returned string around longer than the method that calls your C# callback, consider copying it into another location before freeing the returned memory.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this confuses P/Invoke is unusual memory management semantics implied by this. You effectively return a string, allocated by unknown means, to the caller who then doesn't free it (at least so far as I can see). This is rather problematic design (not thread-safe, and possibly not reentrant), and definitely not typical.

There isn't really anything you can do here with the string, because the C code doesn't actually receive a pointer directly to your string data. Since C# strings are Unicode, and you requested the string to be marshalled as ANSI, a "copy" (with result of Unicode-to-ANSI conversion) will be made and returned. I've no idea about the lifetime of this, nor how to control this, and I don't see any guarantees in the documentation.

So, looks like your best bet is to manage this yourself, using `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` to allocate the buffer (probably just once for all calls, the same as your C code does),  `Encoding.GetBytes` to convert strings to byte arrays, and `Marshal.Copy` to copy the resulting bytes into the allocated buffer.

Comment: Memory allocation by the P/Invoke layer is fairly well-documented. In this case, it uses the default OLE task memory allocator--so CoTaskMemFree should be used to free it on the C side.

Comment: Pavel, thanks for your comments. But I never worked with these guys you're talking about (AllocHGlobal, Marshal.Copy etc). Could you please help me to put it all togheter?? Txs!!!

Comment: Ben, out of curiosity, can you give a link where it describes that? In any case, I doubt the C code is going to `CoTaskMemFree` it, and it seems that it is what it is (i.e. cannot be corrected).

Comment: That's it, the C code is from a third-part company. @Pavel, can you give me an example of using Marshal.AllocHGlobal and Copy, please??? Thank you!!

Comment: Here's a decent article on the subject. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the type of ResponseMsg to a StringBuilder and make sure the capacity is enough to store the response.

Answer (score 0):

The C# code:

```
public delegate void ProcessMessageCallback(StringBuilder ResponseMsg);

static class test
{
    [DllImport("test.dll")]
    static extern void TestCallback(ProcessMessageCallback callback);

    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestCallback(MyCallback);
    }

    static void MyCallback(StringBuilder ResponseMsg)
    {
        ResponseMsg.Append("hi there");
    }
}
```

The C code (in a DLL):

```
typedef int(__stdcall * Callback)(char *message);

__declspec(dllexport) void TestCallback(Callback callback) 
{
    char* test = (char*)malloc(10000);
    test[0] = '\0';
    callback(test);
    printf(test);
    free(test);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about :

```
IntPtr p = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(pmc);
```

Comment: R Ubben, in what point in the code should I used it, and how??