# expose c++-cli dll to c#

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I am generating a dll using c++-cli. 
The class in the dll looks like this:

```
ref class Locator

{
public:
Locator(int HP) : m_HP(HP) { } 
~Locator() 
{ } 
Dictionary<String^, array< Byte >^>^ Locate(Dictionary<String^, String^>^ imgParms) 
{ .....  }

private:
int m_HP;
```

How can I expose it to use it in c#? The class and the members are not being exposed in c#

Comment: If this were a "normal" C/C++ program, you'd use Interop.  Since this is a C++-CLI (managed C++) program, you should already *have* assemblies.  Just reference them in your C# client.  PS: I'm honestly curious why anybody would want to use C++ CLI (in contrast to VB.Net or C# for .Net, or standard C++ for portability and efficiency)?  It's always baffled me...

Comment: That should be `ref class Locator`.

Comment: paulsm4: Sometimes, it's a matter of having native libraries to interop with, and writing the right P/Invoke and ComImport magic can be more difficult than wrapping the whole shebang in a C++/CLI `ref class`. :)

Comment: I have to use C/C++ because I am using OpenCV for image processing but I'll try the ref

Comment: So I added ref to class locator and now it doesn't compile: error C2664: 'cvReleaseCapture' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'cli::interior_ptr<Type>' to 'CvCapture **'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=CvCapture *
1>          ]
1>          Cannot convert a managed type to an unmanaged type

Comment: It compiles now but the class still cannot be seen in c# :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `public` keyword to make managed types visible to consumers of the assembly.  Try

```
public ref class Locator { ... };
```

Answer (score 0):

A question I asked a few months ago, regarding a similar issue :

[How to use a C callback from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166970/how-to-use-a-c-callback-from-c)

Here are a few extra hints in my answer about the problem :

[Calling C++ DLL from C++ works, but not from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345724/calling-c-dll-from-c-works-but-not-from-c-sharp/11403445#11403445)

I read you're using OpenCV, do you know [Emgu CV: OpenCV in .NET (C#, VB, C++ and more)](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) ? :-)

Answer (score -1):

C++/CLI generates standard .NET managed assembly. That's the whole point of C++/CLI => compile an existing C++ code into a managed assembly without rewriting it to a CLS language.

So simply reference this assembly as any other .NET assembly in your consuming project. And then consume:

```
var imgParms = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "foo", "bar" }, { "baz", "bazinga" } };
var locator = new Locator(123);
var result = locator.Locate(imgParams);
// TODO: do something with the result dictionary
```